# $_SESSION variable only stores one value

Tags: php, session

I have this code:

```
// Values of drop-down lists (cmbPosition)
$studPosition = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION['arrayNamePosition'] as $value) {
    $studPosition[$i] = $_GET[$value];
    $i++;
// Calculates the points for each student in the event
    $points = ($_SESSION['noStudents']+1) - $_GET[$value]; 
    echo $points;
    $_SESSION['points'] = $points;
}
```

The code above loops through `$_SESSION['arrayNamePosition']` which contains an array. Every thing works but `$_SESSION['points'] = $points;` is where the problem is (This is the $_SESSION variable which contains `$points`).

When I echo `$points` in the current php form, it outputs: 583276

But when I `echo $_SESSION['points']` inside a while loop in a different php form it only outputs the last element stored in $`echo $_SESSION['points']`points which is 6.

How can I fix this so that `echo $_SESSION['points']` outputs all the values of `$points` in a different php form.

NOTE: I have also put `echo $_SESSION['points']` inside a for loop but it still outputs the last value stored in $points. e.g. output: 666666

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because $_SESSION['points'] itself is not an array. You should change your line to:

```
$_SESSION['points'][] = $points;
```

Comment: So when I output `$_SESSION['points']` do I just  `echo $_SESSION['points']` or use a loop to output the values 583276 in the other form?

Comment: You may use print_r($_SESSION['points']) if it is just for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Variable points is not an array, therefore it contains only last calculated element. Change it to array, then save each value as new element in array.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean that the loop with `echo $points;` outputs you 583276. Like the `$_SESSION['points']`, it stores only one value, but you print the value each time.
I would suggest following changes:

```
$studPosition = array();
$i = 0;
$points = '';
foreach ($_SESSION['arrayNamePosition'] as $value) {
  $studPosition[$i] = $_GET[$value];
  $i++;
  $points = $points.(($_SESSION['noStudents']+1) - $_GET[$value]); 
}
echo $points;
$_SESSION['points'] = $points;
```